# Convert DateTime to a specified Format

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datetime-format

I have this date format  `yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss` ex: `12/02/21 10:56:09`. The problem is, when i try to convert it to different format using this code:

```
CDate("12/02/21 10:56:09").ToString("MMM. dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

It displays `Dec. 12, 2021 10:56:09`.

How can i correctly format it to: `Feb. 21, 2012 10:56:09`? This format is returned when i check balance inquiry fro my SMS based application.

Comment: Your question is backwards. You mean to say "how do I get VB to parse my date as yy/MM/dd?".

Comment: @M.Babcock it added c# tag so that anyone can suggest in vbnet or c# code.

Comment: as it turns out, the code looks the same in either VB or C# ;).

Comment: The DateTime constructor is using the thread's current Culture which for your case is interpreting the first number to be the month.

Comment: @siride there is no CDate() in C#.

Comment: @JaredShaver: the answer code would look the same...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx), e.g.:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("12/02/21 10:56:09", "yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    ).ToString("MMM. dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 10):

Even easier way to convert Date:

```
Convert.ToDateTime("12/02/21 10:56:09").ToString("MMM.dd,yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("12/02/21 10:56:09", "yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var text = dateTime.ToString("MMM. dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are meaning to ask how to get VB to parse the date as yy/MM/dd, the answer is simple: just use `DateTime.ParseExact("12/02/12 10:56:09", "yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")` and then use `ToString()` as before.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("12/02/21 10:56:09", "yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MMM. dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```