# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime C# to Sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am passing a datetime value from C# to SQL Server SP. If I pass the format `dd-MM-yyyy` then it is working fine but not returning any values from SP even there are records of that date. If I run the SP with the format `MM-dd-yyyy`, then it is returning the error "Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.". The SP is

`execute usp_detData '22/12/2012 00:00:00', '31/12/2013 23:59:59'` --- error

`execute usp_detData '12/22/2012 00:00:00', '12/31/2013 23:59:59'` --- working fine

Would you please let me the the solution

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms189491.aspx but you should use Habib's answer.

Answer (score 4):

> I am passing a datetime value from C# to SQL Server SP.

I believe you are passing it via string concatenation. Its better if you use [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) of type `DateTime`  and let the server handle it.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" usp_detData", conn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", DateTime.Now);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    .....
}
```

Also consider using the [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) block in your code with objects which implements [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx). for example. `SqlCommand`, `SqlConnection`, `SqlDataReader` etc.

Comment: Don't you want AddWithValue?

Comment: SqlConnection and SqlDataReader are both IDisposable

Comment: @ta.speot.is, yes Added a reference to that in the answer, but I think the main point is to use SqlParameter.

Comment: If I use the DateTime.Now then the format would be dd/MM/YYYY which is not accepting by sql server.

Comment: @PankajSaha, that is the point of using SqlParameter, your database column type is `DateTime`, right ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
DateTime.ParseExact("12/02/21 10:56:09", "dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    ).ToString("MMM. dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

or go through this question [Convert DateTime to a specified Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371658/convert-datetime-to-a-specified-format)

Comment: Sql Server SP takes Datetime type parameters with the format MM/dd/YYYY and if I try to parse the string to datetime in MM/dd/YYYY then it's shows the error. var sDate = DateTime.ParseExact(startDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: Why dont you simply parse it as : var sDate = DateTime.ParseExact(startDate, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: thanks varun..I have done this already it is returning the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use the format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' and things will all be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using the following code in the C# class  var sDate = DateTime.ParseExact(startDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); it is showing the error String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: First create a date object in your c#, use `ParseExact` with the format of your string date, looking at your post this is probably `MM-dd-yyyy`. When you send the date to SQL server, that's when you either a) send as a date parameter,or b) convert to a string in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`

Comment: @ta.speot.is did you miss the point where in my comment I stated **'a) send as a date parameter'**

Comment: Comments are not answers. Answers are answers.