# Parse string to DateType ASP.NET C# exception - The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, parsing

So I have a date which is in this format. My goal is to add 7 days to this string `startdate` and post it into a database as a string. However, I have to convert it to datetime to allow me to add days to it. I am reading `startdate` from a database but this is what it looks like.

```
string startdate = "10-03-2018 03:15PM";

IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);
DateTime starttime2 = DateTime.ParseExact(startdate, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt", culture);
```

// It is breaking on the above line with the error - The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

```
DateTime endtime2 = starttime2.AddDays(+7);
```

Anyone able to help me solve this issue? I am new to C# and would appreciate any help at all..

Thank you

Comment: _"and post it into a database as a string"_ the next question where i cringe

Comment: You have a space between mm tt...There is no space in 15PM

Comment: I agree with @TimSchmelter. Why do you even want to save a date as a string? Most databases I know of have a special `DATE` data type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String was not recognized as a valid DateTime C# to Sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14686371/string-was-not-recognized-as-a-valid-datetime-c-sharp-to-sql-server)

Comment: Apologies, I meant to say it is already a string because of a javascript textbox function and that is why I need to convert it to date to add my days. I didn't mean to write the posting it as a string, I meant DateTime :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have specified wrong format actually. You should be specifying the following format:

```
"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mmtt"
```

as your date is in format :

```
"10-03-2018 03:15PM"
```

Assuming that the first number us for day and second is for month, otherwise you can swap those.

You can see more details on the usage of [`ParseExact` here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    string startdate = "10-03-2018 03:15PM";

    IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);
    DateTime starttime2 = DateTime.ParseExact(startdate, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mmtt", culture);
```

no space between mm and tt. also this is 12 hours format so `hh`

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you

```
    public static DateTime AddDaysToMyDate(string date)
    {
        return DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mmtt", new CultureInfo("en-US", true)).AddDays(7);
    }
```

Use it as

```
DateTime newDateTime = AddDaysToMyDate("10-03-2018 03:15PM");
```