# how to parse HiddenField value to DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, hidden-field

My **HiddenField** have a value and I want parse it to **DateTime** format

**In code behind**

```
DateTime dateTime;

string start = startDate.Value.ToString();
dateTime = DateTime.Parse(start);
```

my string format: 03/29/2020 - 04/04/2020

but I keep getting this error:

**String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**

Comment: how is your string formated? Please add an [MRE]

Comment: @Ackdari updated in the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse string to DateType ASP.NET C# exception - The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49134441/parse-string-to-datetype-asp-net-c-sharp-exception-the-string-was-not-recogniz)

Comment: @Ackdari, unfortunately, nope

Comment: The problem lies here: `startDate.Value.ToString();` because if you take a look at this example, directly hardcoding the `startDate` yields correct result: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dby8qQ . Please debug and check what value do you get in `startDate.Value.ToString()`

Comment: If `"03/29/2020 - 04/04/2020"` is the value your `start` variable has, then this does not look like a valid date but like a date intervall. You might want to seperate the two dates in the intervall into sperate strings and then parse to `DateTime`s

Comment: @StackOverFlowSavedMyLife If the case is what Ackdari is suggesting then you can see this updated fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dby8qQ

Comment: @Ackdari, u are right, it is not a valid Date format at the first place

Comment: @RahulSharma please post your solution as an answer, since external links might break.

Comment: @Ackdari btw can u please have a look on this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61030630/remain-textbox-value-after-the-page-refreshed

Comment: @RahulSharma can u please have a look on this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61030630/remain-textbox-value-after-the-page-refreshed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your case, it seems that you are getting an incorrect value in your `startDate` which could be: `03/29/2020 - 04/04/2020`. If that is the case, you can do something like:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DateTime dateTime;
        DateTime dateTime1;
        DateTime dateTime2;

        string start = "03/29/2020";
        string incorrectdate=@"03/29/2020 - 04/04/2020";
        string[] parsed=incorrectdate.Split('-');
        dateTime = DateTime.Parse(start);
        dateTime1=DateTime.Parse(parsed[0]);
        dateTime2=DateTime.Parse(parsed[1]);
        Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
        Console.WriteLine(dateTime1);
        Console.WriteLine(dateTime2);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
3/29/2020 12:00:00 AM
3/29/2020 12:00:00 AM
4/4/2020 12:00:00 AM
```

Working Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/dby8qQ