# How i can convert date to text while exporting datagridview to excel?

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I am having a problem while exporting data-grid view to excel. 
In the datagridview there is column with dates like 12/5/2014.

When i export it using this code

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
app.Visible = true;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];

ws.Name = "Exported from gridview";

ws.Rows.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;

for (int i = 1; i < ExcelDGV.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
{
    ws.Cells[1, i] = ExcelDGV.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
}


// storing Each row and column value to excel sheet
for (int i = 0; i < ExcelDGV.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < ExcelDGV.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        ws.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = ExcelDGV.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
    }
}

ws.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit();

wb.SaveAs("c:\\output.xls",Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive , Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

app.Quit();
```

It shows up up like that 12/05/2014 12:00 AM

I don't want it to be like that. 
I want it to just be 12/05/2014.
How i do that in the for loop that is what i mean ??

I want to detect if the cell value is string convert it to this format

and for your information the datagridview already has the date is this format dd/MM/yyyy

this problem only occurred when exporting

any one knows how to solve it ?

Comment: Could you please explain how you *"don't want it to be like that"* - do you just want to export the date part? or different format altogether?

Comment: Is it time format present but not displayed in datagridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help you out;

```
DateTime.ParseExact("12/02/21 12:00 AM", "yy/MM/dd HH:mm tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MMM. dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

But I think this should be reported as a duplicate of [Convert DateTime to a specified Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371658/convert-datetime-to-a-specified-format).

Sidenote: I can't comment yet.

Comment: You may not be able to comment yet, but the 'Flag' Post should still be available. That's where you should go to report a duplicate.

Comment: @jbutler483 ah, my bad. Have done so. Should I delete this post then?

Answer (score 1):

```
                        DateTime MyDate;
                    if (!DateTime.TryParse(ExcelDGV.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString(), out MyDate))
                    {
                        XcelApp.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = ExcelDGV.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        XcelApp.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = MyDate;
                    }
```