# Change format of DateTime

Tags: c#

I would like to change the format of datetime but I get error:

> No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

```
string ret = person.ArkivDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

The type of ArkivDate is `DateTime?`

How can I fix it?

Comment: And the type of `ArkivDate` is...? (Given your previous post, I suspect it's `DateTime?`, in which case you should use `ArkivDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`, as previously advised...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert DateTime to a specified Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371658/convert-datetime-to-a-specified-format)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i guess you're mixing up `DateTime` and `DateTime?`

use `ArkivDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` instead

so your code should look like this:

```
string ret = person.ArkivDate.HasValue ? person.ArkivDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : String.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with fubo's guess that `person.ArkivDate` is in fact `DateTime?` in *C# 6.0* you can use a simple `?.` syntax (`?.ToString()` instead of `.ToString()`):

```
string ret = person.ArkivDate?.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

So when `ArkivDate` is `null` then `ret` will be `null` as well, otherwise `ret` will contain formatted date representation.