# Change Date Format to ddth mmm,yyyy

Tags: c#, datetime, string-formatting, datetime-format

I am printing some dates on my webform.
Currently my Date Format is `dd:mmm:yyyy hh:mm`

How can I change the date format to `ddth mmm,yyyy for` example **17th May,2016** hh:mm

Here is my Code :

```
 lastlogin = DateTime.Parse(dt_LastLoginDetail.Rows[0]["login_time"].ToString());
 lastlogindate = "Last Login Date: " + lastlogin.ToString("dd-MMM-yyy hh:mm tt");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert DateTime to a specified Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371658/convert-datetime-to-a-specified-format)

Comment: if it's look like that kindly suggest me the solution :(

Comment: He is asking for a specific format, This is not a duplicate

Comment: It is easy without the 'th' since you can have 'th', 'st', and 'rd'

Comment: I think the issue is that she wants ordinal suffixes after the day part, so she'd also need it to pick "nd", "rd" or "st" when appropriate. I don't think there's a built-in format for that but I could be wrong!

Comment: Since you mentioned using WebForms, I'd recommend encasing the `st`, `nd`, `rd` and `th` in a [sup](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_sup.asp) tag

Comment: Thanks @Jon but I am finding the solution may be I get successfull

Comment: Thanks @Reddy for understanding me

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer How can I do that ? suggest me please

Comment: By putting a `<sup>` before and a `</sup>` after it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
lastlogin = DateTime.Parse(dt_LastLoginDetail.Rows[0]["login_time"].ToString());
string suffix;
switch (lastlogin.Day) {
    case 1:
    case 21:
    case 31:
        suffix = "st";
        break;
    case 2:
    case 22:
        suffix = "nd";
        break;
    case 3:
    case 23:
        suffix = "rd";
        break;
    default:
        suffix = "th";
        break;
}
lastlogindate = "Last Login Date: " + lastlogin.ToString("dd\"" + suffix + "\" MMM, yyyy hh:mm");
```

.Net does not have built-in method to retrieve 'st', 'nd', etc. So you simply need to determine in the code.

Comment: it printed 17th May 2016 but I want comma after yyyy i.e it should be 17th May ,  2016

Comment: Just add `\",\"` after  MMMM

Comment: Yes now it get printed,I should test it now

Comment: @Alexis Just forgot it, so maybe hard-code all date would be simpler.

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard Date format that generates the "st", "nd", "rd" or "th" suffix for you, as far as I'm aware. You could use the following:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

string suffix = "th";
if (dt.Day < 10 || dt.Day > 20)
{
    switch (dt.Day % 10)
    {
        case 1: 
            suffix = "st";
            break;
        case 2:
            suffix = "nd";
            break;
        case 3:
            suffix = "rd";
            break;
        default:
            suffix = "th";
            break;
    }
}

string format = $"dd\"{suffix}\" MMM yyyy hh:mm";
string s = dt.ToString(format);
```

Comment: Yep. Just like Mango Wong, I forgot about those. It's fixed now, but you might find Mango's solution to be cleaner.

Comment: yes,Thanks a lot Rik. I just marked Mango's answer as answer but I'll vote for your answer and also need your support :)

Answer (score 1):

Any date and time format string that contains more than one character, including white space, is interpreted as a custom date and time format string; for more information:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

For showing 17th May 2016

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd'th ' MMM,yyyy");
```