# Convert DateTime 1/20/2022 8:48:30 PM to 20/01/2022 8:48:30 PM C#

Tags: c#, string, datetime, parsing, time

I basically have two DateTime variables

```
 DateTime dateToday = WorldTimeAPI.Instance.GetCurrentDateTime();       
 DateTime dateFinish;
```

`dateToday` gets current date from the web, with this format 1/20/2022 8:48:30 PM.
`dateFinish` has this other format 20/01/2022 8:48:30 PM, the day first, and then the month, everything else is the same.
I want to be able to parse one of them to match the other one in terms of format so that I can compare them both to know if todays date is greater than date finish by doing this:

```
if(dateToday.CompareTo(dateToEndMission) > 0)
{do stuff}
```

I tried looking at documentation but it has so many different formats that I just couldnt figure out the exact way to do it.

Comment: DateTime variables do not have formats. Formats are applied when they are displayed or converted to string. How do you check that they have different formats? What's the issue you are facing while comparing the dates? How these dates are getting values?

Comment: I check that by debugging, when I inspect the variables in runtime, I can verify that the date is different by checking the date.dayOfYear. The issue is that, I need to parse the string that I get that has the following format: "2/11/2022 6:58:55 p. m." to "11/02/2022 6:58:55 p. m."

Comment: Again: DateTime values **do not have a format**. Strings do. A DateTime is actually stored as a non-human-readable binary value, and when see it in a human-readable way in the debugger that's just a convenience it provides for you. Use `DateTime.ParseExact()` to read the 2nd string into a DateTime value, and then compare the two DateTime values without worrying about the format.

Answer (score 0):

To compare two dateTime values in an if statement you can do:

```
if(firstDate.Date > secondDate.Date)
{
  //Do something...
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try and keep things as simple as possible.

As stated above you can compare date time with the > operator. But I would go further and ask why you're using that api to get the current date and time when you could just use this

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
```

This should fix your problem, because you should be initialising date time in the same way now. If not, then I suggest you take a look at this other questions answers:

[Convert DateTime to a specified Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371658/convert-datetime-to-a-specified-format)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm using that api because, as far as I am concerned, DateTime.Now gets your system date, and users must not be able to change that so that it does not interfere with the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the ParseExact method

```
DateTime dateToday = DateTime.Now;
DateTime dateFinish = DateTime.ParseExact("20/01/2022 10:56:09", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
if (dateToday > dateFinish)
{
    // do something
}
```